# How can I get "ProgramData" path using QStandardPaths

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Is there a way to get `ProgramData` path in QT using `QStandardPaths`.

Details:

1. I want to know how to get `ProgramData` path by using functions of QStandardPaths class.
2. I want cross-platform solution, that is why I want to use QStandardPaths. I believe QT provides such a solution but I could not find it.
3. People may ask why I want that, or may suggest it is not good to use `ProgramData` path. First of all, I am planning to copy there user-independent config file of my app. I want all users to be able to reach that file, only for reading. I am going to locate necessary files in setup step. (We can discuss that situation though, if this is not a good way to do it)

What I have tried already:

1. `QStringList locations = QStandardPaths::locateAll(QStandardPaths::DataLocation, QString(), QStandardPaths::LocateDirectory);`
2. `QStringList locations2 = QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::DataLocation);`
3. I tried to run my QT as admin (to see if problem is due to some privilege issue) and nothing has changed

With the functions from point 1 and 2 I also tried to use `QStandardPaths::GenericDataLocation` as a standard location type. Actually, I have tried all types in [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html) link which has "ProgramData" in its explanations

At the end, all I get are:

1. > C:/Users/myUser/AppData/{Local|Roaming}
2. > /Data
3. empty `QString`.

Comment: This does not really answer your question directly, but for storing user-independent configurations I suggest using [`QSettings`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) with [`QSettings::SystemScope`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#Scope-enum).

Comment: cant we use  something like this   QString path1 = "C:/ProgramData/";
        QDir dir1(path1);
        dir1.setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot|QDir::Files);  not sure just asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Qt, already reported in [QTBUG-44348](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-44348) and in [QTBUG-40565](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40565)